# Como deixar o select obrigatório? e tambem selecionado por padrão a primeira opção disponivel?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, select, sql-select

Estou com um sistema em php que gera selects de acordo com as informações do banco de dados, no caso gostaria de deixar estes selects obrigatórios pois se não passam despercebido e também deixar sempre a primeira opção selecionada como padrão.

abaixo o trexo do codigo onde é criado os selects:

```
if(get_field('atributos')){
    $selects = array();
    $i=0;
    $atributos = explode(PHP_EOL,get_field('atributos'));

    foreach($atributos as $atributo){
        $opcoes = explode(':',$atributo);
        $name = $opcoes[0];
        if(!empty($opcoes[1])){
            $opcoes = explode(';',$opcoes[1]);
        }
        $selects[$i] = array('name'=>$name,'options'=>$opcoes); 
        $i++;
```

Comment: Eu não sei como funciona no wordpress mas tentaria algo como `$selects[$i] = array('name'=>'teste' ,'options'=> 'algum valor', 'seletected' => true);` antes do foreach.

Comment: vou tentar! obrigado

Comment: Normalmente  tem que colocar 'required' na tag <select>, dessa forma ao dar submit ele irá validar quais 'select' estão vazios